# Python: how is `None` evaluated in logical expressions, in relation to other boolean values?

Tags: python, logical-operators, nonetype

In Python 3...

- Sample 1:

```
s: str = None
b: bool = True
b = (s != None) and (s != "some-not-allowed-value")
print (b)
```

Displays `False` (*as it seems intuitive*)

---

- Sample 2:

```
s: str = None
b: bool = True
b = (s) and (s != "some-not-allowed-value")
print (b)
```

Displays `None`

**Why ? How is that `s` field evaluated ?**

Comment: `x and y` always evaluates to one of `x` or `y`; the boolean value of either is only used to determine which one.

Comment: `x and y` is equivalent to `x if not bool(x) else y`.

Answer (score -1):

In python, `None` interacts as follows with booleans:

```py
>>> print(None and False)
None
>>> print(None and True)
None
>>> print(None or False)
False
>>> print(None or True)
True
```

Note that the type hints (`s: str`) are only *hints*, and are ignored at Runtime